# Why does C# compiler generate anonymous delegate without closures as an instance method, rather than as a static method on the same type?

Tags: c#, delegates, anonymous-methods

Consider the following code creating and running anonymous delegate:

```cs
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Action action = () => Console.WriteLine("Test");
        action();
    }
}
```

In .NET 5, when decompiled using ILSpy with disabled "decompile anonymous methods" option (to see the real implementation done by the compiler), it can be observed, that the code is translated to the following:

```cs
internal static class Program
{
    [Serializable]
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private sealed class <>c
    {
        public static readonly <>c <>9 = new <>c();

        public static Action <>9__0_0;

        internal void <Main>b__0_0()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test");
        }
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        (<>c.<>9__0_0 ?? (<>c.<>9__0_0 = <>c.<>9.<Main>b__0_0))();
    }
}
```

Why does `<Main>b__0_0` have to be an instance method on another type, rather than a static method on the `Program` type? The method does not capture any local variables or state.

Comment: Probably makes it easier to generate, as it requires less special-casing. An optimizing Jitter would probably remove `this` anyway

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface, could you please describe this part "An optimizing Jitter would probably remove this anyway" more? In which part of the code will this happen?